# How to check if second-tier (nested) key exits in python list/dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, nested

Please correct me if any of my terminology is wrong.

I'm trying to check if a nested key exists in a python list/dict.

For example, below I am assigning a value to a variable based on whether or not the key for that value exists in a list/dict returned by the [Requests' library's `.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) (it's not clear from the docs what exactly it returns).

This works for checking if a key exists in the first dimension of the `jsonassoc` list/dict:

```
 #works
 is_oa = jsonassoc[u'is_oa'] if u'is_oa' in jsonassoc else ""
```

However, I'm not sure how to check if a key exists when it is nested in the second dimension.

I've tried:

```
#doesn't work:
mendeley = jsonassoc[u'readers'][u'mendeley'] if u'readers'[u'mendeley'] in jsonassoc else "" enter code here
# neither does simply this
mendeley = jsonassoc[u'readers'][u'mendeley'] if u'mendeley' in jsonassoc else ""
```

How can I make a check for, for example, the 'mendeley' key, which looks something like this in the list/dict?

```
readers: {
     mendeley: '1',
     citeulike: '3',
     #etc.
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use dictionary [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
d.get('key1',{}).get('key2')
```

doing so you will by-pass check for the key.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like

```
mendeley = jsonassoc[u'readers'][u'mendeley'] if 'readers' in jsonassoc and 'mendeley' in jsonassoc['readers']
```

Alternatively, you could use the `get` function to assign the default:

```
mendeley = jsonassoc.get('readers', {}).get('mendeley', '')
```

There are also some libraries for working with JSON that will allow you to access nonexistent keys, and return some empty value instead of raising an error.  [safeJSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/safeJSON/0.9b) is such a library, created by the New York Times.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I like this one. Very nice and stays true to the Python ternary conditional. I'll try this!

Comment: @Gnuey: I think a solution using `get` is actually slightly cleaner, since it doesn't involve repetition of the key names.  However, if you're doing this a lot, you might want to use a library or set up some kind of general solution for accessing nonexistent keys.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll give `.get` a go then. What do you mean when you say "accessing nonexistent keys"? Do simply mean checking for them?

Comment: @Gnuey: I mean something that allows you to do `jsonassoc['readers']['mendeley']` and returns an empty value (instead of raising an error) even  if there are no `'readers'` and/or `'mendeley'` elements in your dict.  That's what the safeJSON library I linked to does.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I'll try that out. Thanks for pointing me to safeJSON!